# How can I sort an array from 2 fields?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following format of an array

```
[HomeTeam] => Brazil
[AwayTeam] => Croatia
```

How can I sort the array based on home and away teams.

So all Brazil will come first if they are a Home or an away team.

Do I need an array_multisort? I've given it a try, but not getting the right results.

Comment: `I've given it a try, but not getting the right results.` <-- the most common lie on SO. If you made an attempt, post it. Otherwise it's irrelevant because it tells us nothing.

Comment: you could try manually rearranging the array with a loop and checking each one

Comment: RUJordan - you could have just asked, instead you wasted your own time with some nobbish comment. Bellend!

Answer (score 0):

use `usort`:

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a > $b;
});
```

you will need to modify `return` condition depending on how you want it to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

On [www.php.net](http://www.php.net) you can find this function:

```
<?php
function array_orderby()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $data = array_shift($args);
    foreach ($args as $n => $field) {
        if (is_string($field)) {
            $tmp = array();
           foreach ($data as $key => $row)
                $tmp[$key] = $row[$field];
            $args[$n] = $tmp;
           }
    }
    $args[] = &$data;
    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
    return array_pop($args);
}
? >
```

you can use it like this:

```
$sorted = array_orderby($data, 'field', SORT_ASC);
```

Source::
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php